# Clang Error - stddef file not found?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, clang, stdio

After upgrading to Ubuntu 13.10 "Saucy", Clang now gives me the error message:

```
clang -Wall -Werror -std=c99 -ggdb -O0 5.1.c -o 5.1
In file included from 5.1.c:1:
/usr/include/stdio.h:33:11: fatal error: 'stddef.h' file not found
# include <stddef.h>
          ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [5.1] Error 1
```

BTW the header I included was `stdio.h` not `stddef.h` but I am assuming that `stdio.h` references or `#includes` `stddef.h`

Answer (score 24):

This error appeared for me when trying to run `clang-tidy` without `clang` installed.

Installing clang fixed this error. IMO this error occurs when `clang-tidy` looks for headers in GCC and system paths and `clang` version/symlink of these headers are missing.

Comment: I encountered this error when running `clang-tidy` too. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: Same issue but when using qtcreator on Ubuntu 20. I have multiple clang versions installed :(

Answer (score 9):

It's a know bug in ubuntu. Take a look here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/llvm-defaults/+bug/1242300

It appears that a temporary workaround is to correct the symlink:

> For the 3.5 LLVM toolchain it seems that the symlink
>   /usr/lib/clang/3.5/include erroneously points to
>   ../../llvm-3.4/lib/clang/3.5/include, but should instead point to
>   ../../llvm-3.5/lib/clang/3.5/include
>
> The workaround (of course) is to manually correct the symlink.
>
> For the 3.4 toolchain the /usr/lib/clang/3.4/include doesn't exist at
>   all. I have not tried LLVM 3.4 on Ubuntu so I don't know if createing
>   a symlink to ../../llvm-3.4/lib/clang/3.4/include will fix the
>   problem, but it does seem likely.

[Source](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/llvm-defaults/+bug/1242300/comments/9)

Comment: Given that this bug was fixed in 2015 and the problem persists at least until Ubuntu 18.04, it's probably not the entire story!

Answer (score 4):

Using clang-tidy from cmake and gcc you can add the following in your CMakeLists.txt

```
if(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${CMAKE_CXX_IMPLICIT_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES})
endif()
```

This will result in the "compile_commands.json" file to contain the correct gcc includes.

The solution comes from the kitware issue tracker: [Missing c++ header path in compile_commands.json](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/20912#note_795673)

*This answer is a bit off topic but this is the top hit on search engines for my specific issue*

Answer (score 2):

Please note that I resolved the above error by performing:

```
$ sudo apt-get install clang
```

In my particular case, there is likely an issue with something in my `cmake` files which I haven't determined yet.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, This is because of the file  **compile_commands.json** dont exist, just

```
cmake -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON .
```

solve it.

Answer (score 0):

For clang16, You might try this:

```bash
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/lib/llvm-16/lib/clang/16/include/
```

(substitute the 'llvm-16/lib/clang/16' with the actual version you installed)

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this with a Debian 12 (Bookworm) Docker container where I had been running Doxygen with clang-assisted parsing. I'd built my container to install the latest clang (`clang-18`) from LLVM's [APT repo](https://apt.llvm.org/) as well as the default version of gcc and g++ for Debian 12 (`gcc-12 g++-12`).

Removing the LLVM APT repo caused the default `clang-14` package to be installed and that has resolved the include error.

I guess **don't** try to install a `clang` version much newer than your system's GCC toolchain?