# Using libclang 6.0.1: stddef.h not found

Tags: c++, clang, libclang

To get started with libclang,  I build a very simple program that tries to load a very simple source file.  It fails with 'stddef.h' file not found.

Here is the program using libclang:

```
#include <clang-c/Index.h>
int main() {
    CXIndex index = clang_createIndex(1,1);
    const char *source_path = "foo.cpp";
    clang_createTranslationUnitFromSourceFile(index,"foo.cpp",0,0,0,0);
}
```

(For conciseness,  I left out code that is irrelevant to reproducing the issue).

And here is the file I am trying to load, foo.cpp:

```
#include <stddef.h>
int main() {}
```

I am using LLVM and Clang 6.0.1,  compiled from source as follows:

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$HOME/local -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=$HOME/local -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
make
make install
```

A quick search yields this promising post: [Clang Error - stddef file not found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20587228/clang-error-stddef-file-not-found#20587653)  Unfortunately,  this is about llvm 3.5,  and I am using llvm 6.0.1.  Also,  the directory $HOME/local where I installed LLVM and Clang does not have a /usr/lib directory,  so the solution proposed there does not work here.

The stddef.h header is present at `$HOME/lib/clang/6.0.1/include/stddef.h`. Explicitly adding this path as a -isystem option to the clang_createTranslationUnitFromSourceFile call solves the problem.

Moreover,  the include search path used by clang_createTranslationUnitFromSourceFile is not the same as that used by clang++;  `clang++ foo.cpp` works without errors.

Is there any documentation on the include search path used by clang_createTranslationUnitFromSourceFile and similar functions in libclang, so that I can determine which include paths need to be added?

Any other suggestions on how to invoke clang_createTranslationUnitFromSourceFile with a correct include search path,  equivalent to the path used by clang++?

Comment: I too am having problems with the include paths for clang_parseTranslationUnit.  Building with clang is OK but the same -I arguments with clang_parseTranslationUnit are not fully working.  I note that both clang and libclang are using HeaderSearch.cpp.

Answer (score 2):

`libclang` works as if you tried to compile the file, i.e.: to parse a file it needs to know where to look for the headers, and potentially other info such as macro definitions, compile flags, etc.

[clang_createTranslationUnitFromSourceFile](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/group__CINDEX__TRANSLATION__UNIT.html#gaf45dfbcd2e4d8e9eeab4778f994a74c3) has two parameters: `num_clang_command_line_args` and `clang_command_line_args`. There you need to pass actual header search path, e.g.:

```
const char *cli_args[] = { "-I", "~/local" };
clang_createTranslationUnitFromSourceFile(index, "foo.cpp", 2, cli_args, 0, 0);
```

Comment: OK,  but when I replace '#include <stddef.h>' by '#include <string>',  I still get the same error about stddef.h,  and no error about string.h.  What is the difference between string.h and stddef.h?  It looks as if "/usr/include" is automatically part of the include search path, and "~/local/lib/clang/6.0.1/include" (which contains stddef.h) is not.

Comment: If I add "-I" "~/local/lib/clang/6.0.1/include" to the clang_createTranslationUnitFromSourceFile call,  it works. Remaining question is: which include paths are implicitly added,  and which ones do I need to add manually?  The answer for clang_createTranslationUnitFromSourceFile seems different from the answer for the clang command.

Comment: And it is not documented in the libclang documentation

Comment: @ygramoel here is a good answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11946294/dump-include-paths-from-g

Comment: that helps to find the include search path for the clang command, but not for the clang_createTranslationUnitFromSourceFile call. These search paths seem to differ.  I edited my question t clarify this point.  Thank you for your suggestions until now,  they really helped me to get the question clear.