# my complier use clang ,it compile well, but allways show some error, just like they can't find the lib path

Tags: clang

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ACiU.png)

Actually, when i compile the file ,it works perfectly, but the wrong hint disturb me .

I have installed the stdc++ clang,gcc. they are no problem.
How can i fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

[Clang Error - stddef file not found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20587228/clang-error-stddef-file-not-found)
I finally find out the answer. fixing it by add

```
if(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${CMAKE_CXX_IMPLICIT_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES})
endif()
```

to my cMakelists.txt